# When did current source control management emerge?

Tags: version-control, history, scm

The use of source control management tools is nowadays a standard
practice in the software industry.  Furthermore, it seems that there
is quite a strong consensus (for deliverables) to have an instable
branch where new features arrive and one or several stable branches
where only bugfixes are added.  I am interested into the history of
the emergence and consolidation of these practices.  Can anybody
provide information about the following milestones?

- When SCM was used for the first time in an organisation developing software?
- When was released the first free-software SCM?
- When was released the first SCM shipped by a software company?
- When was given the first talk about SCM in a developer's meeting
  of international importance?
- Which alternative schemes to the *one unstable and one or more
  stable branches* scheme are used today, by a significantly large
  community (e.g. a large company).

(Note that if a project uses topic branches, development happens in
numerous branches, but none of them correspond to deliverables.)

Comment: the "alternative schemes" part of your question is very broad - I've worked with all kinds of setups, several being quite unique to the company's needs and its processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SCCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System) is one of the oldest ones, dating back to 1972. It has been introduced to early versions of Unix and is now part of the Single Unix Specification.

Comment: +1 And still in use today

Comment: But not used outside of Bell Labs until the commercial release of Unix System III in 1982?

Answer (score 6):

The first free source management system was [RCS](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System) developed by Walter F Tichy in 1982.

If you follow the references in his original 1982 paper, cited in the Wikipedia article, you will get answers to some of your other questions.